# Proof strategy/writing for change of variables

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Claim: If $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$, then $f(x+c)=g(x+c)$ for all x.

Proof (attempt): Set $u=x-c$, and substitute $x=u+c$.
$f(x)=g(x)$ implies $f(u+c)=g(u+c)$ for all $u$. 
Because $u$ is a dummy variable, set $u=x$ and $f(x+c)=g(x+c)$.

Is this valid proof? Is it right to set $u=x-c$ and use $u=x$? If not, how can this be proven more correctly or elegantly?

Comment: Well, it's a little unnerving that you're using $x$ to mean two different numbers over the course of your proof. Otherwise, valid.

Comment: @JahanClaes Yes, I'm not happy about that either. But other than the suggestion by Mike Haskel to change the claim, is there something else you'd recommend?

Comment: Don't write two $x$s. And in general, be precise with your "for all"s. So for instance, you should specify that for all $u$, there exists an $x$ such that $x=u+c$. Then just say that this implies that for all $u$, $f(u+c)=g(u+c)$, and leave it as is.

Comment: @JahanClaes Great suggestions. I actually thought of concluding with $f(u+c)=g(u+c)$, but then I thought, since $x=u+c$, this is just $f(x)=g(x)$, so I haven't proven anything. But I guess this latter thought is fallacious, and seems to go back to what Mike Haskel said about a function is not dictated by the letters we use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is valid, but I think you're making the situation more complicated than it really is. Your claim has two parts: a hypothesis, and a conclusion. The hypothesis is "for all $x$, $f(x) = g(x)$." The conclusion is "for all $x$, $f(x + c) = g(x + c)$." Both the hypothesis and conclusion discuss, separately, a claim about "all $x$", and the fact that they both use the same letter, $x$, is a red herring: you can rewrite the conclusion as "for all $y$, $f(y+c) = g(y+c)$" without changing anything.

With the above in mind, here's how I would prove the claim. Assume that, for all $x$, $f(x) = g(x)$. We wish to show that, for all $y$, $f(y+c) = g(y+c)$, so let $y$ be an arbitrary number. We know that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all numbers $x$, so in particular we know $f(y+c) = g(y+c)$ (since $y+c$ is a number). Since $y$ was arbitrary, we know that $f(y+c) = g(y+c)$ for all $y$.

Comment: Mike Haskel, I understand your proof, but I am trying to understand why we can't use "for all $x$" for both the hypothesis and the conclusion. Say $f(x)$ models the sent signal at time $x$, and $g(x)$ models the received signal at time $x$. The hypothesis says both signals are the same. Then the conclusion states if we delay the sent signal by time $c$, the received signal is still the same as the one sent, just delayed by the same amount of time. If we use another variable $y$ to denote the same time-coordinate, wouldn't this be confusing to the reader? (Continued next comment...)

Comment: But to be mathematically rigorous, is it true $x$ have (erroneous) double meanings the way I have stated the claim?

Comment: @FreshAir It is harmful to read too much meaning into which letters we use. A function is just something that takes input values and produces corresponding output values; it doesn't make sense to say that something is "a function of $x$" or "a function of $y$". It's more clear to use two different variables in this case, since they are "bound" to two different uses of "for all."

Comment: @FreshAir To expand further, when analyzing a statement and trying to prove it, it's a good idea to look at all the different variables used. They can be *free*, like $f$ and $c$ in your statement, and the statement is about some particular choice of values for those; it might in general be true for some functions $f$ and not for others. The alternative to being free is for a variable to be *bound* by some phrase like "for all $x$", "there is some $x$", "for infinitely many different $x$", or similar. In those cases, you can match up instances of those variables with the places they're bound.

Comment: Mike Haskel, these are really helpful. So then, $x$ in my claim is bounded twice, and it's not appropriate to bound the same variable multiple times in a single argument, isn't that right?

Comment: Mike Haskel, if you could point me to any resources that may help me understanding these issues better and resolve concerns such as that in my previous comment, I'd appreciate it.